# asterisk Call ID in sipml5

Tags: asterisk, sipml

How do I get asterisk call Id (uniqueid in `cdr` table) (for instance, 1487150355.465) in sipml5 client.
As far as I looked, I see only
https://www.doubango.org/sipml5/docgen/symbols/SIPml.Session.html#getId
which has (afaic) no relation to asterisk id.

I know I can set additional headers in asterisk and set there call id, but it cannot be done for some organizational reasons.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asterisk unique channel id(not call id) assigned to channel. By default asterisk not send that via sip or other protocol.

So no, you can't get it without do something on asterisk.

Comment: Does asterisk has that channel id to write it in `cdr` table along with uniqueid? Thanks

Comment: Don't know. You have read source of driver, sipml is too new.

Comment: Turned out, there is.
I've added a custom column `sip_callid` to the `cdr` table and write there by

```Set(CDR(sip_callid)=${SIPCALLID})```

in ```extensions.conf```